# Config GEM Staging ENV is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, staging

Im using `config gem` on Ruby 2.2.1 and rails 4.2.1
I have some setting under directory

```
config/settings/staging.yml
```

But after I make deploy to staging (I'm ussing flightplan to do it)
Staging is taken the seeting under my directory

```
config/settings/production.yml
```

Somebody have an idea what could be the problem here?

Thnks

Comment: Is the environment variable `RACK_ENV` set to `staging` in your staging environment?

Comment: Hello @Brian Yes it is set as `staging` but is not working